# Fetch model data from remote

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am switching to Laravel 5.2 framework, but all of my users/useful data is stored in a different location. Here's how the project stack works:

**1.** The PHP framework stores a solicitation (row) in a table (MySQL) and waits for a response.

**2.** An application running on the server sweeps this table periodically for open solicitations, if so, it writes another field of the same row with the desired data, in a size-delimited string.

This is the main data pipeline methodology between the web presentation and the data server, being used to authenticate, fetch reports, graph data or whatever.

I'd like to use Laravel (maybe Lumen) for this PHP portion of the project,  to serve mainly as a RESTFul API for Angular.js, but I'm unsure of how I 'convert' this size delimited string into a usable Laravel Model.

Comment: Can we see an example of the string?

Comment: It varies from requisition types.. but mostly integers and strings.. Maybe if I develop a service provider for that? Database interaction seems weird inside of a service.

Answer (score 0):

I assume having two different database connections settings is not viable? 
As in your Eloquent models you're able to configure what database connection to use.